# Why can't I get mpiexec to connect to another node?

Tags: mpi, mpich, mpiexec

I am trying to set up a distributed computing cluser via MPI (MPICH2), running on Windows XP. I am trying to run a single command, along the lines of

```
>> mpiexec -hosts 2 localhost 1 other-computer 2 notepad.exe
Aborting: unable to connect to other-computer
```

What are possible causes? I know that the network is fine, since ping works:

```
>> ping other-computer
Pinging other-computer [IPADDRESS] ...
Reply from IPADDRESS: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
...
```

mpiexec.exe and smtpd.exe are both listed as exceptions in Windows Firewall.

What could be possible causes of this problem? My Google-fu has failed me! (Could it be something to do with authentication? I tried using -logon, but that doesn't change anything. If it might be an authentication problem, how can I find my own username / password (or does it use the computer username/password)?)

Please forgive ignorance, as I am unfamiliar with the workings of MPI.

Comment: Do you mean `smpd.exe` or `mpd.exe`? A process named `smtpd.exe` would be a mail server. Do you have the launcher daemon running on `other-computer`? You can check the task manager if you don't know.